# Android AdView Giving 'heap_msk' flags and Async Pixel Transfer Warnings

Tags: android, asynchronous, admob, heap-memory, adview

I am working on an application that uses ads. Whenever I disable the ads, this issue **completely disappears**. This makes me confident that it's the AdView (or AdRequest) causing this.

First, I get this warning:

```
 [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
```

Then I get x5 of each (x10 total) in a row:

```
 heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
 heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
 heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
 heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
 heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
 heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
 heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
 heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
 heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
 heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
```

Again, these don't show up when ads are disabled. As far as I can tell, it's not harming my app in any way. However, I prefer to have as few "*warnings*" as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but maybe some more info. I got this same issue, but it turned up when I upgraded my phone to Kitkat. So probably has something to do with the use of Chromium.

Hope somebody has some more info.

gr

Answer (score 0):

It is not a *WARNING*. Your log clearly shows that it is an *INFO* message.
Nothing to see here, move along.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the heap_msk things are errors for sure and I think they have something to do with the async pixel message.
By the way, I think chromium gives js errors as info